# How can I create a realistic 3d model from my 2d photos of furniture?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, images, 3d, 3ds-max

Before you point your finger and laugh, please take into consideration that my boss is asking me to do this for him. As a faithful employee with some Photoshop skills and no experience with 3d modeling, I'm trying to figure out if it is possible and what it will entail.

**My Task**: I need to be able to take images of furniture and rotate them in 3 dimensions so I can use them to stage empty rooms for a project. I only have one or two images of each piece of furniture, so software like 123dapp.com/catch by Autodesk won't work.

**My Tools**: Photoshop CS6, Illustrator CS4 (and pretty much anything else CS4), 3DS Max 2013, and any open source software.

**My Questions**:

1)  With my available tools, what's my best approach as someone who has no 3d modeling experience?

2)  How long should creating a high-quality 3d model of something like [this](http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/7607/woodenchair1.jpg) or [this](http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/3230/barstool1.jpg) take (again, for someone who has no 3d modeling experience but can generally pick things up quickly)?

**My Appreciation**:

Thank you **very** much for taking the time and energy to read this and *hopefully* for providing a constructive answer. I may be asking the impossible, but I see "virtual staging" companies who do this as a business, so there must be a way.

Comment: Unless it's a life-long desire (or at least just a desire) of yours to learn how to model in 3D, I'd suggest you diplomatically tell your boss to do the natural thing and hire a professional. And if you do end up learning and doing these for him, ask for a raise because you will deserve it. Having said that, Blender is a great open source, cross platform soft.

Comment: Thanks Yisela for the advice. Any idea how much hiring someone to do one of these models would cost?

Comment: Depends hugely on location and amount of work, but it's usually charged by the hour. I'd try in one of the big freelance portals (just google freelance design). It helps a lot if you have your materials ready and a clear explanation of what exactly you need, and always ask for samples of previous work. EDIT: I just remembered, last time I checked, Google sketchup was really easy to use.

Comment: Sketchup is worth some playing with, but it's not a full fledged 3D rendering tool. If the end result is a fully modelled, surface mapped, shaded and lit model of a room, then you might need to look at other options.

Comment: I just want to add: I took drafting in high school (pencil), and used CAD software and 3d animation in college (monochrome), but I NEVER really got a handle on 3d modeling. Nor enjoyed it (which may have had something to do with the fact that to render a camera pan with 1 light and a sphere primitive took 8 hours). The domain is really quite different from GD and 2d work.

Comment: I agree on Sketchup, it's free and takes only a few hours to be able to handle it. Great piece of software. In sketchup you can also download countless of existing models from the Google Sketchup 3D library, where you can edit look-a-like models of furniture so you don't have to make them from scratch.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its nolonger in scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own Furniture model in Autodesk MAX check tutorial below

http://www.techtut.com/Tutorial/3D-studio-max/79-How-to-create-a-modern-chair.html

and export to photoshop check tutorial below how to export 3ds max file to photoshop

http://area.autodesk.com/forum/autodesk-3ds-max/modeling/export-to-adobe-photoshop-extended-and-other-applications/

and finally handle in photoshop.

Comment: Autodesk is great software. But do note that it's also complex. People that work in the land of autodesk products tend to be full time autodesk folks. It'll take some dedication to become fully immersed in it.